# How to implement installed UPI app in Android?

Tags: android, payment-gateway, upi, phonepe

I created an Android application that has listed monthly rent in the billing list activity. Each list item has a `Pay` button. My requirement is while clicking on the `Pay` button, it should list installed UPI apps. If we select an app and make a payment, my application should get a success or failure based on the payment.

Initially, my targeted customers will be in India. So I have to support GPay, PhonePe, Paytm and Amazon Pay.

Comment: Is there something like this exists for Flutter? which supports Android and iOS both

Answer (score 0):

Hey firstly you have to Register as an independent developer with NCPI. or please checkout this website also https://nfinite.in/.

Once your application is approved, you will be provided with a public and private key.
Create a UPI deep link URL using the following format:

```
upi://pay?pa=<UPI ID>&pn=<Name>&tn=<Transaction ID>&cu=INR
```

Here is an example of how to implement in your Android app:

```
 // Get the UPI ID and transaction ID from the UI.
        String upiId = "your_upi_id";
        String transactionId = "your_transaction_id";

        // Sign the UPI deep link URL.
        String signedUpiUrl = signUpiDeepLinkUrl(upiId, transactionId);

        // Create an intent to launch the UPI payment app.
        Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_UPI_PAY);
        intent.setData(Uri.parse(signedUpiUrl));

        // Start the UPI payment app.
        startActivityForResult(intent, 100);
```

here is onActivityResult Code

```
 if (requestCode == 100 && resultCode == RESULT_OK) {
            // The payment was successful.
            Log.d("UPI", "Payment successful");
        } else if (requestCode == 100 && resultCode == RESULT_CANCELED) {
            // The payment was canceled.
            Log.d("UPI", "Payment canceled");
        } else {
            // The payment failed.
        Log.d("UPI", "Payment failed");
    }
```

here is signUpiDeepLinkUrl function code

```
private String signUpiDeepLinkUrl(String upiId, String transactionId) {
        // Get the public key from NCPI.
        String publicKey = "your_public_key";

        // Sign the UPI deep link URL.
        String signedUpiUrl = signUpiUrl(upiId, transactionId, publicKey);

        return signedUpiUrl;
    }
```

Comment: Any monthly fee?

Answer (score 0):

**NOTE: It's not directly possible to get the list of payment apps. Though you can list the well-known payment apps by their package name.**

For example, you can get all installed apps list and then filter by package name which includes some of the famous paymeny apps like GPay, PhonePe, Paytm, Paypal, etc.

So, it's advisable that you integrate the default payment behaviour where you can show the payment apps sheet and user would have to choose the appropriate app to proceed forward.

Here is how to do that (Using library).

**Dependency:**

```
implementation "com.shreyaspatil:EasyUpiPayment:2.0"
```

**Code:**

```
private void makePayment(String amount, String upi, String name, String desc, String transactionId) {
        // on below line we are calling payment method and passing
        // all parameters to it such as upi id,name, description and others.
        final EasyUpiPayment easyUpiPayment = new EasyUpiPayment.Builder()
                .with(this)
                // on below line we are adding upi id.
                .setPayeeVpa(upi)
                // on below line we are setting name to which we are making payment.
                .setPayeeName(name)
                // on below line we are passing transaction id.
                .setTransactionId(transactionId)
                // on below line we are passing transaction ref id.
                .setTransactionRefId(transactionId)
                // on below line we are adding description to payment.
                .setDescription(desc)
                // on below line we are passing amount which is being paid.
                .setAmount(amount)
                // on below line we are calling a build method to build this ui.
                .build();
        // on below line we are calling a start
        // payment method to start a payment.
        easyUpiPayment.startPayment();
        // on below line we are calling a set payment
        // status listener method to call other payment methods.
        easyUpiPayment.setPaymentStatusListener(this);
    }
```

Comment: Is this secure library?

Comment: Yes it is. It just simplifies the process so that you don't have to go through all the steps.

Comment: Could not find com.shreyaspatil:EasyUpiPayment:2.0.

Comment: unfortunately the library is not working